# finding missing data between two tables mysql workench

Tags: sql, dataframe, uitableview, datatables, mysql-workbench

I have some difficulties to answer the following questions

1 Write an SQL statement to show the SKU and SKU_Description for all items that have not been ordered.

```
SELECT SKU,SKU_DESCRIPTION 
FROM SKU_DATA
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEM
ON SKU_DATA.SKU =ORDER_ITEM.SKU;
```

I do not know how to write the condition to compare and display the SKU that is present in SKU_Data but are not present on order_item...

Here the different tables available

```
Inventory (WarehouseID,SKU,SKU_Description,QuantityOnHand,QuantityOnOrder)

Order_Item(OrderNumber,SKU,Quantity,Price,ExtendedPrice)

Retail_order(OrderNumber,StoreNumber,StoreZip,OrderMonth,OrderYear,OrderTotal)

SKU_Data(SKU,SKU_Description,Department,Buyer)

Warehouse(WarehouseCity,WarehouseState,Manager,SquareFeet)
```

Thank you

Comment: You could likely use an [exists or not exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) query to help. (the `not exists` would be more applicable for what you need)

Answer (score 1):

Not much sure. But from your query, It seems that you need `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT SKU,SKU_DESCRIPTION 
FROM SKU_DATA
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM ORDER_ITEM OI
         JOIN RETAIL_ORDER RO ON OI.ORDERNUMBER = RO.ORDERNUMBER
        WHERE SKU_DATA.SKU =OI.SKU
          AND RO.ORDERYEAR >= 2012);
```

Comment: If I want to add the condition for items that have not been ordered since 2012. Do I have to create another query ?

Comment: I tried with AND but it did not work. The OrderYear is on retail_order table. Thank you.